# Ng-repeat - filter out by object's constant property with different values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to solve a ng-repeat issue.  I can see 2 ways to solve it 1. Using a `filter` to not repeat/display the object's property of `category`, which I am not sure how to do without using it's value or 2. If there is a way to say `ng-repeat="i in items.drinks && items.sandwiches`.

Is there no wildcard to say "category":"whatever"?

So in this case I am drilled down to where `item` = `bottled-drinks` and/or `sandwiches`.  So when I do `ng-repeat="i in item"`  `category` is lump in.  I don't want it.

json -

```
food-items": {
                "bottled-drinks": {
                    "category": "Bottled Drinks",
                    "drinks": {
                        "drink1": {
                            "title": "Drink Me 1",
                            "calories": "170"
                        },
                        "drink2": {
                            "title": "Drink Me 2",
                            "calories": "230"
                        },
                        "drink3": {
                            "title": "Drink Me 3",
                            "calories": "88"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sandwiches": {
                    "category": "Sandwiches",
                    "sandwiches": {
                        "sandwich1": {
                            "title": "Sandwich Me 1",
                            "calories": "230"
                        },
                        "sandwich2": {
                            "title": "Sandwich Me 2",
                            "calories": "111"
                        },
                        "sandwich3": {
                            "title": "Sandwich Me 3",
                            "calories": "700"
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Do you control that data structure source? it is a very unfriendly structure

Comment: @charlietfl  No, but how would you structure it differently?

Comment: Arrays of objects with consistent property names would be a whole lot easier to work with and in order to do filtering or sorting you would need to map to that

Comment: @charlietfl Can you give me an example and I'll suggest it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your existing data structure, this would get you where you want to go.

> **NOTE:** If you changed your data structure this would be much easier to implement. I'll show an example at the bottom.

Here is the fix for your current configuration.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="firstKey in firstKeys">
    <div ng-repeat="secondKey in secondKeys">
      {{ foodItems[firstKey][secondKey] }}
    </div><br>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.firstKeys = ["bottled-drinks", "sandwiches"];
  $scope.secondKeys = ["drinks", "sandwiches"];

  $scope.foodItems = {
    "bottled-drinks": {
      "category": "Bottled Drinks",
        "drinks": {
          "drink1": {
            "title": "Drink Me 1",
            "calories": "170"
          },
          "drink2": {
            "title": "Drink Me 2",
            "calories": "230"
          },
          "drink3": {
            "title": "Drink Me 3",
            "calories": "88"
          }
        }
      },
      "sandwiches": {
        "category": "Sandwiches",
        "sandwiches": {
          "sandwich1": {
            "title": "Sandwich Me 1",
            "calories": "230"
          },
          "sandwich2": {
            "title": "Sandwich Me 2",
            "calories": "111"
          },
          "sandwich3": {
            "title": "Sandwich Me 3",
            "calories": "700"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This will result in a div with these values

```
{"drink1":{"title":"Drink Me 1","calories":"170"},"drink2":{"title":"Drink Me2","calories":"230"},"drink3":{"title":"Drink Me 3","calories":"88"}}

{"sandwich1":{"title":"Sandwich Me 1","calories":"230"},"sandwich2":{"title":"Sandwich Me 2","calories":"111"},"sandwich3":{"title":"Sandwich Me3","calories":"700"}}
```

> Now you can use the keys you wish to use, but this is not that easy to do. If your data was instead structured like this...

```
$scope.edibles = [
  {"category": "Bottled Drinks",
   "types": [
       {"title": "Drink Me 1",
       "calories": "170"},

       {"title": "Drink Me 2",
        "calories": "230"},

       {"title": "Drink Me 3",
        "calories": "88"}
    ]},

    {"category": "Sandwiches",
     "types": [
       {"title": "Sandwich Me 1",
        "calories": "230"},

       {"title": "Sandwich Me 2",
        "calories": "111"},

       {"title": "Sandwich Me 3",
        "calories": "700"}
      ]}
    ]


<div ng-repeat="edible in edibles">
  <div ng-repeat="foodType in edible.types">
    Type: {{ foodType.title }}<br>
    Calories: {{ foodType.calories }}
  </div><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I only put this here because the comment-box is a pain sometimes:

Flat arrays are the easiest, most flexible and most efficient to work with:

```
$scope.foodItems = [  // Array (not object)
     { 
         "id": "drink1", 
         "label": "Drink Me 1",
         "calories": "170"
         "category": "bottled-drinks", 
     },
     { 
         "id": "sandwich1", 
         "label": "Sandwich Me 1",
         "calories": "270"
         "category": "sandwiches", 
     },
     ... (ALL ITEMS)
];

// Categories are a different resource, so better keep them in their own array. 
// You'll thank me when you want move your stuff to some server-API.
$scope.categories = [
   { "id": "sandwiches", "category-label": "Sandwiches" },
   { "id": "bottled-drinks", "category-label": "Bottled Drinks" },
];
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <h2>{{ category.label }}<h2>
    <div ng-repeat="item in foodItems" ng-if="item.category==category.id">
        <h3>{{ item.label }}</h3>
        <p>Calories: {{ item.calories }}</p>
        <p>Description: {{ item.description }} (or whatever) </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You'll notice that you have to filter out some stuff (ng-if) but if you compare with SoEzPz's solution (which is not bad either) you'll have a much easier time when you want to show some custom list - for example show all items with less than 300 calories. (Since you don't need to concat arrays or whatnot.)

(There is a way to use angular $filters instead of ng-if... something like.... `ng-repeat="item in foodItems | filter:{category:'sandwiches'}"` (wild guess here!) But I'll leave it for you to research since I can't promise the syntax is correct from the top of my head.

Also, to be thorough, I would use a number based id (less messy), and use ng-repeat [track by](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates) to gain some minor performance.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer I want, but I did an ng-if and in the controller I passed i then checked to see if i.title exist... if so display if not don't.  There has to be a better way.